# $_FILES contains the uploaded file while Laravel request does not

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, file-upload

I am using Laravel as an API and AngularJS as the front-end to interact with it. I am trying to upload a file using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) but I am facing a weird issue.

The global variable `$_FILES` only contains the uploaded while `$request->file('img')` is empty so the custom request validation fails as it can not see the uploaded file.

I have found couple of answers stating to add `use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;` to the controller so I can access the uploaded file but I can't so far. I have checked the code having `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form but still nothing works

How can I access the file and at the same time the validation rules are applied correctly?

Angular Form:

```
<div class="small-6 medium-3 columns small-centered">
    <form name="products.storeForm" ng-submit="products.store()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="products.product.name" name="name" required>
        <label>Image</label>
        <img ng-src="{{image_source}}">
        <input type="file" name="img" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*" ng-model="products.product.img">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Angular Service:

```
service.store = function(product){
    console.log(product.img)
    return Upload.upload({
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
        method: 'POST',
        sendFieldAs: 'form',
        fields: {
            name: product.name
        },
        file: product.img,
        fileFormDataName: 'image'
    })
};
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the debug mode to true? Maybe there is an error or something.

Comment: It's already set to `true` and there are no errors at all

Comment: Can you show your form and controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the means to test this, but I the fact that you are passing the image with the `image` key would be my starting point (on your Angular upload service):

```
fileFormDataName: 'image'
```

But you are trying to fetch it using the `img` key in Laravel:

```
$request->file('img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below test code at laravel controller method before `$request->file('img')` and I hope you will get the your answer.

```
print('<pre style="color:red;">');
print_r($request->all());
print('</pre>');
exit;
```